# Get Old Record Count from Table without Date Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle DB Table with more than 1 million records and there is no 'Date' column.
I need to find and delete old records that are created/inserted before 1 year.
Is there a way to find-out the records that are older than 1 year in the table?
Are there any system columns that auto generate/track this that I can use to achieve what I need?
Appreciate any help, please.

Comment: You'll need to add a date column and either modify the process that inserts or add a trigger to set the date on insert. Then, a year from now, you'll be able to run your delete on a real date column, and any row with a NULL value has to be even older. Don't be in a rush to delete old rows. There's rarely a pressing reason to do so. If it's about performance, proper query tuning and/or indexing will make the table size irrelevant.